# Can I set OpenGL camera to look at positive z?

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math

Since OpenGL camera basically looking at negative z direction,

```cpp
int front = 0, right = 0;

// Press W and move backward?!
front += glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_W) == GLFW_PRESS ? -1 : 0;
front += glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_S) == GLFW_PRESS ? 1 : 0;

// Press D to move right makes sense!
right += glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_D) == GLFW_PRESS ? 1 : 0;
right += glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_A) == GLFW_PRESS ? -1 : 0;

Translate(right, 0, front);
```

As you can see in the code, in order to move camera forward, I have to move it's z position *backward*, which completely disobeys my intuition.

So in order to deal with this problem, I deliberately multiplied `scale(1, 1, -1)` to my view matrix, like

```cpp
viewMatrix = glm::inverse(GetWorldTransform());
viewMatrix = glm::scale(glm::mat4(1), glm::vec3(1, 1, -1)) * viewMatrix;
pvMatrix = perspectiveMatrix * viewMatrix;
```

...Which is not very pretty. Is it okay to solve this problem like this? Or, Is there any way to set OpenGL's camera to look at positive z direction? Or, Is there a prettier way to deal with the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenGL *doesn't have a camera*. It just renders whatever happens to fall into the viewing volume in clip space. The "camera" is just either a completely abstract mental model, or some higher-level abstraction around some transformation math you add on top. As such, you completely *define* what a "camera" is and where it looks at.

> Since OpenGL camera basically looking at negative z direction.

In OpenGL 1.x, there actually *was* a convention which had something to do with this. The functions `glFrustum` and `glOrtho` were build  for an *eye space* where `-z` was the viewing direction . However, you can use whatever matrices you want, and you could do so since GL 1.0. (The rest of the functions which also adhere to this convention, like `gluLookAt`, `gluPerspective`, etc. were *never* part of OpenGL).

> Is it okay to solve this problem like this?

Well, it is mathematically correct. In your case, you basically end up with `P * S * V`.

> Or, Is there any way to set OpenGL's camera to look at positive z direction? Or, Is there a prettier way to deal with the problem?

There is. Instead of doing `P * S * V` you could do `P' * V` where `P' = (P * S)`. And you can calculate `P'` without doing the multiplication with a scale matrix (which in this particular case only flips the signs of the 3rd column anyway).

Since you use the glm library, you can let glm do it for you directly - the glm library for some reason uses the old GL conventions *by default*, but it doesn't enforce them. It leaves you the option to use for example [`glm::perspectiveLH`](http://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.8/api/a00169.html#ga34048da27c559f1ac8e9550d169dd6f3) or `glm::perspectiveLH`. Old GL convention is to use a right-handed view space, but you can directly create the "left-handed" version of the projection matrix.

Comment: Oh it works. And it fits perfectly with `glm::lookAtLH()` . By the way, why OpenGL sticks to RH? Since I have used popular game engines like Unity, It's pretty odd for me...

Comment: Well, as I said, OpenGL never really cared. And with "modern" GL (everything since the introduction of shaders in GL 2.0 15 years ago), there is absolutely nothing left in GL about this. However, the old GL convention was just what the typical math conventsions were. You draw a 3D coordinate frame on paper with x to the left, y upwards, and z out of the page. Also note that none of these conventions are better or worse than others. Ultimately, it doesn't matter, it only gets ugly if you mix code parts  and/or data created with with different conventions in mind.